# Views contextual filter: content has taxonomy term ID

Tags: views, ubercart

I have a view set up to display Ubercart products with a contextual filter for Content: Has taxonomy term ID.

I then have another view in a block for choosing the taxonomy term to display all products with that term in the main view.

See below screenshots of the views settings for the main view, the contextual filter for the main view (with all available vocabularies activated), and the block view where the taxonomy term is selected.

This all works perfectly for one specific vocabulary, but doesn't work for any others - the products are not displayed in the main view. I cant find any settings anywhere which would only allow this to work for one specific taxonomy vocabulary. When i set the bock view for choosing the taxonomy term to another vocabulary, it does show in brackets how many products there are for each term, but clicking on the term does not display the products in the main view.

As I said it all works perfectly for one vocabulary but not any others, and I cant see anything anywhere which is making either of these views tied to a specific vocabulary.

What am i missing?

[image: Main View]

[image: Main View contextual filter]

[image: Block view for choosing taxonomy term]

Comment: Is catalog the one that it works for? I think I'm following your question but you have a filter set in that last screen for catalog, maybe if I'm understanding it right you need to remove that filter or change it to all of the vocabularies it will work.

Comment: Catalog doesn't work, another vocabulary called manufacturers does work. The filter in that last view is there so that only those terms are available to select as options for filtering the main view - but just as a test I set that filter to all vocabularies and that resulted in all terms for every vocabulary being listed, but when I click on a term from catalog the items are not displayed in the main view, if I click on a term from manufacturers the items are displayed.

Comment: You may have to add a relationship to pull in the other taxonomy term data, usually this is set up when you first setup a view and then relationships are added to bring in other data.